# php for loops not working - second loop not working after first loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have two for loops in php.  Only the first loop is outputted.  Why is the second for loop being ignored?  I have spent time looking at this code and trying different things so any thoughts will be much appreciated.  I have tried each for loop independently and they work so i know the code is correct.

The problem just seems to be when I'm asking a second for loop to run after the first.

Many Thanks

```
$str_test = file_get_contents("...");    
$count = 0;
$count2=0;


for($y = 0; $y<strlen($str_test); $y++)
{
      $pos2 = strpos($str_test, "<div class=\"f-reviews-title f-reviews-title--noSpace\" itemprop=\"author\">",$count2);
      if($pos2 == $count2){
           $pos2 = substr($str_test, $pos2+196);       
           $pos3 = strpos($pos2, "</a>");
           $author= substr($pos2, 0, $pos3);
           echo '<br>';
           echo $author;
           echo '<br>';
       }
       $count2++;
}

for($i = 0; $i<strlen($str_test); $i++)
{
     $pos = strpos($str_test, "<p class=\"f-reviews-txt\" itemprop=\"reviewBody\">", $count);
     if($pos == $count){    
          $pos= substr($str_test, $pos+47);
          $pos4 = strpos($pos, "</p>");
          $review= substr($pos, 0, $pos4);          
          echo '<br>';
          echo $review;
          echo '<br>';
     }
     $count++;
}
```

Comment: More information would be welcome, what are you trying to do? Also, on a side note, don`t use functions inside your for() loop construct, just store the number of iterations ( the total ) in a variable. Also, have you tested a simple echo in the second loop, regardless of the if() statement?

Comment: Thank you for this Rajdeep.  Doing the var_dump didn't work because it was outputting the whole page from $str_test.  Based on your suggestion i tried using a separate $str_test for the second loop I called it $str_test2 but that didn't work either, the first loop was outputted and then nothing from the second loop.  I thought because I was using a separate $str_test it would have worked.

Comment: Thans Merv, i have tested a simple echo in the second loop.  My simple message was being echoed multiple times which shows that the 2nd for loop was being worked through but no output was shown.